# Need suggestion to use suitable design pattern to create JAVA objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I am currently having below parent child relation java objects 
JCL > JOB > steps > step > dd

Class looks like below

```
public class Jcl {
Private  Job job;
}

public class Job {

private  String jobname;
//Below is direct property of job object
 private  List<Jobparam> jobparam;  
//Below is child object of the job object
 private  List<Step> step;


}

public class Step {
private  String stepname;
//Below is direct property of step object
 private  List<Stepparam> stepparam;
//Below is child object of the step object
 private  List<Ddstatement> ddstatement;
 }


public class Stepparam {
private  String name;
private  String value;
}

public class Jobparam{
private  String name;
private  String value;
 }
```

I am using getters and setters to create objects with new instance of each object.

```
  Job job = new Job();
    ArrayList<Jobparam> myList = new ArrayList<Jobparam>();

    job.getJobparam().addAll(myList);


   Step step = new Step();
    ArrayList<Stepparam> myList = new ArrayList<Stepparam>();


   jcl.getJob().getStep().add(step);
```

And also jobparam and stepparam have same property.(I want to reuse but donno how)
I feel I am creating each new object every time and this long coding can be avoided by java design pattern.
Any suggestion  how should I proceed to make simple code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Jcl {
    Private  Job job;
}
```

Snippet above isn't really parent-child relation. You're only defining the attribute of class, which you have defined.

However such hierarchical relations could be used to simplify your last two classes eg.:

```
public class Parent {
    private  String name;
    private  String value;
}
```

```
public class Stepparam extends Parent {
    // whatever makes it different from Jobparam 
}
```

```
public class Jobparam extends Parent {
    // whatever makes it different from Stepparam 
 }
```

I'd suggest you to google `object relations in java` or check out [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/association-composition-aggregation-java/).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a common class for the parameter types since they are the same

```
public class Parameter {
    private  String name;
    private  String value;
}
```

and then to declare the job and step list members to be

```
List<Parameter> ...
```

I would also suggest adding wrapper methods for adding stuff to list, it makes the code clearer and the List is hidden and it will be easier to change to another collection type if you want. For instance

```
public class Job {
    //other stuff

    public void addJobParameter(Parameter parameter) {
        jobparam.add(parameter);
    }

  // and/or

    public void addJobParameters(Collection<Parameter> parameters) {
        jobparam.addAll(parameters);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor for classes `Job` and `Step` and inside them initialize the list like below:

```
public class Job {
    private  List<Jobparam> jobparam;
    private  List<Step> step;

    public Job() {
        this.jobparam = new ArrayList<Jobparam>();
        this.step = new ArrayList<Stepparam>();
    } 
}
```

For classes `Stepparam` and `Jobparam` you can create a base class and extends it, but it seems me that a `Map<String, String>` jobparam and a `Map<String, String>` step could be more appropriate of `List<Jobparam>` jobparam and `List<Step>` step, so you should not have to define the classes `Stepparam` and `Jobparam`. You can check map documentation at [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java./util/Map.html).